# Controls on Form appearing as transparent

Tags: c#, winforms

In my Windows Form project, I have a dataGridView and a textbox that are both appearing transparent.
In the picture, I have one dataGridView with no data appearing normal and one dataGridView with data from XML file that is appearing transparent. If I remove the data from that grid view, it appears normal. After adding the data to it, it becomes transparent. I have not added any code to change the appearance of the datagridview. What could be causing this?

[image]

Comment: Apparently there is a difference between the Element when Empty - and when containing something invisible. This is Windows Forms, a 2 decades old technology.  It has those kinds of limitations, design choices and odities all over the place.

Comment: @Chris: _This is Windows Forms, a 2 decades old technology. It has those kinds of limitations, design choices and odities all over the place_ Pardon my french, but this is utter nonsense! - The most likely reason is that he has set a `TransparencyKey` the happens to collide with the color of the cells.

Comment: @TaW yep, it was the transparencyKey. Thanks for the help